# ошибка ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app' (python - flask)

Tags: python, flask

есть файл app.py

c данным кодом

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///test.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class Article(db.model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    text = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
    intro = db.Column(db.String(300), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Article %r>' % self.id



@app.route('/')
@app.route('/home')
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")


@app.route('/about_us')
def about():
    return render_template("about.html")


@app.route('/user/<string:name>/<int:id>')
def user(name, id):
    return "User page: " + name + " - " + str(id)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

я не знаком с веб разработкой, только начал изучать flask по видео уроку на ютубе(https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL0lO_mIqDDFXiIQYjLbncE9Lb6sx8elKA)

но столкнулся с ошибкой:

from app import db

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'

погуглил проблему, но ничего не сработало

---

> > > from app import db

C:\Users\Danil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy_*init*_.py:833: FSADeprecationWarning: SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and will be disabled by default in the future.  S
et it to True or False to suppress this warning.
warnings.warn(FSADeprecationWarning(

Comment: у вас файл называется `app.py` и так же вы определили переменные 4,5 строки.
либо измените название файла, либо название переменных и 98% что всё заработает

Comment: вылезла ошибка ImportError: cannot import name 'db' from 'test' (*путь*\Python\Python38\lib\test\__i
nit__.py)

Comment: @Danil Выглядит так, будто есть ещё какие-то файлы в проекте, которые друг на друга связаны в неправильной последовательности. Если такие файлы есть, то опишите их отредактировав исходный вопрос.

Comment: не совсем понял, что вы имеете ввиду под: файлами в проекте, которые друг на друга связаны в неправильной последовательности

Comment: Вы опять выбрали имя модуля, которое уже занято. Назовите например `my_test_flask.py`

Comment: папка ".ide" ,                            папка "static" ,                       папка "templates",               test.py

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_test_flask'

Comment: Обратите внимание, что во втором трейсбеке вы даже приводит путь, откуда импортируется модуль `test` - `(*путь*\Python\Python38\lib\test\__init__.py)` - это путь к модулю стандартной библиотеки

Comment: Убедитесь, что вы запускаете скрипт с импортом из папки, которая находится в области видимости

Comment: FSADeprecationWarning: SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and will be disabled by default in the future.  S
et it to True or False to suppress this warning.
  warnings.warn(FSADeprecationWarning(

Comment: Показывайте весь трейсбек. Совершенно не понятно, что именно вызывает эту ошибку

Comment: C:\Users\....\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py:833: FSADeprecationWarning: SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and will be disabled by default in the future.  S
et it to True or False to suppress this warning.
  warnings.warn(FSADeprecationWarning(

Comment: Полный трейсбек включает в себя строку запуска программы

Comment: from app1 import db

C:\Users\Danil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy_init_.py:833: FSADeprecationWarning: SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and will be disabled by default in the future. S et it to True or False

Comment: @Danil "FSADeprecationWarning" - это предупреждение, а не ошибка